# Easiest way to allow for empty strings in Document Listener

Tags: java, swing

Whenever I erase a value from a textfield, I get an error stating: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String. Simply put, if the user makes a mistake, I want him to be able to erase the entry in the text field and enter a new entry. Is there a simple fix for this using the below code?

```
jTextField5.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

              updateField();
            }
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
              jTextField5.setEnabled(true);
              if(!jTextField6.isEnabled())
              {
                  jTextField6.setEnabled(true);
              }
              updateField();

            }
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
              updateField();
            }

             public void updateField() {
             double a= Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
             double b =Double.parseDouble(jTextField5.getText());
             double c = Double.parseDouble(jTextField4.getText());

            {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that each `JTextComponent` contains content prior to parsing its text

```
if (!jTextField5.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
   double b = Double.parseDouble(jTextField5.getText());
   ...
}
```

Aside: You might want to catch the `NumberFormatException` should any non-numeric values be entered